# Motivation behind $\langle \overrightarrow{u}, \overrightarrow{v}\rangle=(B_x-A_x)\cdot (D_x-C_x)+(B_y-A_y)\cdot (D_y-C_y)+(B_z-A_z)\cdot (D_z-C_z).$?

Tags: geometry

Let us write

$$\mathbb R^3=\{A=(A_x, A_y, A_z): A_x, A_y, A_z\in \mathbb R\}.$$

For me a vector with initial point $A\in\mathbb R^3$ and final point $B\in\mathbb R^3$ is the set

$$\overrightarrow{AB}=\{(C, D): (A, B)\sim (C, D)\}$$

where $(A, B)\sim (C, D)$ means

\begin{align*} 
B_x-A_x&=D_x-C_x\\
B_y-A_y&=D_y-C_y\\
B_z-A_z&=D_z-C_z. 
\end{align*}

I define the scalar product of $\overrightarrow{u}=\overrightarrow{AB}$ and $\overrightarrow{v}=\overrightarrow{CD}$ as

$$\langle \overrightarrow{u}, \overrightarrow{v}\rangle=(B_x-A_x)\cdot (D_x-C_x)+(B_y-A_y)\cdot (D_y-C_y)+(B_z-A_z)\cdot (D_z-C_z).$$

What is the motivation behind the sum on the left hand side?

Thanks.

P.s.: I don't want to define $\langle\overrightarrow{u}, \overrightarrow{v}\rangle$ through

$$\langle \overrightarrow{u}, \overrightarrow{v}\rangle=\|\overrightarrow{u}\|\|\overrightarrow{v}\|\cos \theta(\overrightarrow{u}, \overrightarrow{v})$$

where $\theta(\overrightarrow{u}, \overrightarrow{v})$ is the angle between $\overrightarrow{u}$ and $\overrightarrow{v}$, for lenghts and angles must be a consequence of the existence of a scalar product, not the converse. By the same reason, I can't motivate the definition using orthogonal projections.

Answer (score 1):

The connection between $x \cdot y = x_1y_1 + x_2y_2 + x_3y_3$ and $x \cdot y = \|x\|\|y\|\cos(\theta(x, y))$ is the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines, which states that these two quantities are equal (at least in $\mathbb{R}^2$). This gives a geometric derivation since the law of cosines can be proved using geometry.

For a more algebraic derivation in $\mathbb{R}^2$, let $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and let $e_1 = (1, 0)$. Note that $x \cdot e_1 = x_1$ and that $x_1 = \|x\|\cos(\theta(x, e_1))$. Then you can check algebraically that the dot product is invariant under geometric rotations, so that $x \cdot y = \|x\|\|y\|\cos(\theta(x, y))$ holds for all $y \in \mathbb{R}^2$.